# Сайт не видит sitemap

Tags: laravel, robots.txt, sitemap

помогите пожалуйста разобраться в проблеме.
Создал файл sitemap.xml, с ним все ок, прогнал по специальным сервисам, ошибок нет, залил в корневую директорию сайта там где лежит robots.txt
В роботе добавил:
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: [http://www.название-сайта/sitemap.xml](http://www.xn----7sbabaiwnln9ae9cq/sitemap.xml) (вместо названия сайта поставил что нужно)

Так не работает, нагуглил что в .htaccess нужно добавить еще строку -
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

Добавил, не помогло. Проверял через сайт название-сайт.сom/sitemap.xml не видит в обеих случаях
Роботса видит таким образом. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Сайт сделан на Laravel есть предположение что там он должен генерироваться автоматически и это нужно настраивать в коде. Мои предположения верны или можно делать как я описывал выше?

Comment: На всякий случай, файл `sitemap.xml` должен лежать не в корне сайта(проекта), а в папке `public`

Comment: спасибо огромное, помогло)